# Check to see the X element in all lists meets or exceeds value C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a variable in my code that is a list of lists and I'm trying to find out how many of the 3rd item in each List matches or exceeds a test value of 50. I know this can be done in a simple loop but I was wanting to know if there was a much easier way to complete this task in Linq or something similar

This is how I would do it in a loop:

```
int count = 0;
foreach(var list in <IEnumerable<IEnumerable<double>> masterList)
{
    if (list.ElementAt(2) >= 50)
    {
         count++;
    }
}
```

Is there a much easier way of doing this?

Comment: Your syntax is not valid. But for clarity, is the type of `masterList` an actual `List` or is it an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<double>>`? If the latter then none of the answers below are valid since they all rely on an indexer that does not exist. But you call it a List of Lists which may be causing confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use LINQ `Count`:

```
int count = masterList.Count(x => x.ElementAt(2) >= 50);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use LINQ and you have an `IEnumerable` of `IEnumerable`s like the question *code* says (and not a List of Lists like the question *text* says), you'd have to combine `Count` and `ElementAt` (not an indexer):

```
var count = masterList.Count(c => c.ElementAt(2) >= 50);
```

Be careful because this only works if you guarantee all your enumerables have at least three items. If the *underlying* enumerables aren't `IList<T>` (but rather, non-materialized `IEnumerable`s) it may be expensive to call depending on how many "sub lists" you have since they have to each be iterated up to the n'th item (fortunately *only* 3rd in this case but could be worse if you needed, say the 100th and you have 1,000 of them).

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq for this solution.

```
Int index = 2;
Int value = 50;

Bool value = (list.Select(sublist => sublist.Any(ele => ele[index] >= 50)).Count > 0);
```

Comment: It's Linq, not 'link'.